# problema al querer crear proyecto con laravel 6 + vue

Tags: laravel, nodejs, vue.js, php7, laravel-6

No puedo instalar correctamente vue con laravel 6 ( tambien pasa con react + laravel 6 ).

Estoy tratando de instalar Vue para laravel version 6, he seguido la documentacion del paquete y todo me funciona bien salvo un ultimo paso.
Al ejecutar el comando php artisan ui vue --auth o php artisan ui react --auth pide realizar al final npm install && npm run dev pero ahi inician los problemas.

Estas son las versiones que uso:

```
npm 8.19.2
Node v18.12.1
PHP 7.4.33
Laravel 6.20.44
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#writing-vue-components

Estos son los comandos que uso, estos comandos no me dan error:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel VueLaravel "6.*"
composer require laravel/ui:^1.0 --dev
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Apartir de aqui empiezan los errores, cuando ejecuto npm install me aparecen los siguientes errores:

```
npm install

npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url-loader@2.3.1: package is bloated with temp files (fixed in 2.3.2)

added 1185 packages, and audited 1186 packages in 4m

78 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

46 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 39 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Ejecute npm audit:

```
# npm audit report

axios  <=0.21.1
Severity: high
Axios vulnerable to Server-Side Request Forgery - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4w2v-q235-vp99
axios Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cph5-m8f7-6c5x
Depends on vulnerable versions of follow-redirects
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install axios@1.2.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/axios

follow-redirects  <=1.14.7
Severity: high
Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor in follow-redirects - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pw2r-vq6v-hr8c
Exposure of sensitive information in follow-redirects - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-74fj-2j2h-c42q
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install axios@1.2.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/follow-redirects

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install laravel-mix@6.0.49, which is a breaking change
node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/chokidar
    laravel-mix  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of extract-text-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of file-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of html-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of imagemin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of img-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of style-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of terser
    Depends on vulnerable versions of vue-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-cli
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/laravel-mix
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
        webpack  1.12.3 - 5.0.0-rc.6
        Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
        Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
        node_modules/webpack
          css-loader  0.6.0 - 3.6.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-extract-imports
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-local-by-default
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-scope
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-values
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/css-loader
          extract-text-webpack-plugin  >=0.1.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
          file-loader  0.5.0 - 5.1.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/file-loader
          friendly-errors-webpack-plugin  >=1.7.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
          optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || >=4.0.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
          sass-loader  <=8.0.2
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/sass-loader
          terser-webpack-plugin  <=2.2.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/webpack/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
          webpack-cli  <=0.0.8-development || 1.3.0 - 4.0.0-rc.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/webpack-cli
    webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.7.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    Depends on vulnerable versions of selfsigned
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server
  fast-glob  <=2.2.7
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/fast-glob
    globby  8.0.0 - 9.2.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of fast-glob
    node_modules/globby
      imagemin  6.0.0 - 6.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of globby
      node_modules/imagemin

json5  <2.2.2
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in JSON5 via Parse Method - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9c47-m6qq-7p4h
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install laravel-mix@6.0.49, which is a breaking change
node_modules/adjust-sourcemap-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/json5
node_modules/file-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/html-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/style-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/vue-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/vue-style-loader/node_modules/json5
node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/json5
node_modules/webpack/node_modules/json5
  loader-utils  <=1.4.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of json5
  node_modules/adjust-sourcemap-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/file-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/html-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/style-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/vue-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/vue-style-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/loader-utils
  node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-utils
    adjust-sourcemap-loader  <=2.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of object-path
    node_modules/adjust-sourcemap-loader
      resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 1.0.3 - 4.0.0-beta.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of adjust-sourcemap-loader
      Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
      node_modules/resolve-url-loader
    html-loader  <=1.0.0-alpha.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    node_modules/html-loader
    img-loader  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    node_modules/img-loader
    postcss-loader  <=3.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    node_modules/postcss-loader
    style-loader  0.8.2 - 1.1.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    node_modules/style-loader
    vue-loader  2.0.0 - 16.0.0-rc.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of vue-style-loader
    node_modules/vue-loader
    vue-style-loader  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
    node_modules/vue-style-loader

node-forge  <=1.2.1
Severity: high
Open Redirect in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8fr3-hfg3-gpgp
Prototype Pollution in node-forge debug API. - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5rrq-pxf6-6jx5
Improper Verification of Cryptographic Signature in `node-forge` - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-2r2c-g63r-vccr
Improper Verification of Cryptographic Signature in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x4jg-mjrx-434g
Improper Verification of Cryptographic Signature in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cfm4-qjh2-4765
URL parsing in node-forge could lead to undesired behavior. - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gf8q-jrpm-jvxq
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/node-forge
  selfsigned  1.1.1 - 1.10.14
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-forge
  node_modules/selfsigned

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 5.0.0-rc.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/postcss-svgo
        cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.8
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
        node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
          cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.1.11
          Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
          node_modules/cssnano

object-path  <=0.11.7
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in object-path - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-v39p-96qg-c8rf
Prototype pollution in object-path - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cwx2-736x-mf6w
Prototype Pollution in object-path - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8v63-cqqc-6r2c
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install resolve-url-loader@5.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/object-path

postcss  <7.0.36
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install laravel-mix@6.0.49, which is a breaking change
node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/icss-utils/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-scope/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-values/node_modules/postcss
  icss-utils  <=3.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/icss-utils
  postcss-modules-extract-imports  <=1.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports
  postcss-modules-local-by-default  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default
  postcss-modules-scope  <=1.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-scope
  postcss-modules-values  <=1.3.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-values

terser  <4.8.1
Severity: high
Terser insecure use of regular expressions before v4.8.1 and v5.14.2 leads to ReDoS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4wf5-vphf-c2xc
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install laravel-mix@6.0.49, which is a breaking change
node_modules/terser

46 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 39 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

La estructura de mi package.json esta asi:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Que tengo que hacer para que no salgan esos errores y pueda ejecutar npm run dev?

Comment: laravel 6 esta muy desactualizado, no se recomienda su uso 46 \vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 39 high)` son demaciadas vulneravilidades

Comment: @John, no entiendo, eso significa que no hay solucion o para ahorrar muchos problemas es mejor actualizar laravel + php? ( no tengo permisos para actualizar las versiones )

Comment: no es nada recomendable usar esas versiones, lo mejor es estar siempre actualizado, deberas obligarte a trabajar minimo con laravel 8 ahora si quieres hacer puertas traceras y dejar el codigo asi tendras que forzar todas las dependencias